# AWS Free Account, how do I know when I will be charged

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am planning to use a AWS free account to learn Amazone Web Services.  How do I know which options I use in the account will get charged?

When I finish the free trial period how do I cancel the account?

Comment: here you can get all information https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Also, there are warnings if you select something that is not eligible for the AWS free usage tier before you make the changes that would affect it.

Answer (score 0):

During the configuration of the services, AWS always displays which services are allowed on Free Tier. This could be the first point: no Free Tier label = you will be charged.

The second one is an alarm creation in Cloudwatch about finance limit: if it is not 0, you will be alarmed.

The cancellation is easy: you have to log in with your root account, and you can just submit a cancellation request. After the account has been suspended, you have 30 days until they will delete it (but the resources will be deleted immediately).